# chatterAnswers:SearchAsk Cannot read property 'ACTION' of null

Tags: visualforce, chatter-answers

I have a simple page that's using the chatteranswers:searchask component:

```
<apex:page >
<body>
    <div>
        <chatteranswers:searchask id="mySearchAskComponent" communityId="MY_ID_HERE" />
    </div>
</body>
```

If I leave the category blank when I post the question, an error message appears on the page, and the view doesn't refresh.  The error is: "Unknown Error : Cannot read property 'ACTION' of null".  If i navigate to the list of questions, I can see that my question was inserted despite the error message.
[image: Image showing error message]

[image: Image showing that question was inserted]

How do I prevent this error from occurring?